# Colocar o resultado da função

Tags: php, html5

ola estou querendo exibir o meu resultado da minha função calcularImc mas não esta indo, poderiam me ajudar sou meio leigo em php.

erro que esta dando quando executo o site: 
Notice: Undefined property: Pessoa::$calcularImc in C:\xampp\htdocs\pw1\turma_a\0608\exemploFormulario\php\classes\Pessoa.php on line 69

```
Pessoa.php  
<?php  
class Pessoa
{
    private $nome;
    private $idade;
    private $peso;
    private $altura;

    public function setNome($nome)
    {
        $this->nome = $nome;
    }

    public function setIdade($idade)
    {
        $this->idade = $idade;
    }

    public function setPeso($peso)
    {
        $this->peso = $peso;
    }

    public function setAltura($altura)
    {
        $this->altura = $altura;
    }

    public function getNome()
    {
        return $this->nome;
    }

    public function getIdade()
    {
        return $this->idade;
    }

    public function getPeso()
    {
        return $this->peso;
    }

    public function getAltura()
    {
        return $this->altura;
    }

    public function calcularImc($peso, $altura)
    {
        return $peso/($altura * $altura);
    }

    public function cadastrar($nome, $idade, $peso, $altura)
    {
        $this->nome = $nome;
        $this->idade = $idade;
        $this->peso = $peso;
        $this->altura = $altura;
    }

    public function exibir()
    {

        return"<b>Nome</b>: $this->nome<br>
               <b>Idade</b>: $this->idade<br>
               <b>peso</b>: $this->peso<br>
               <b>altura</b>: $this->altura<br>
               <b>imc</b>: $this->calcularImc<br>";
    }

}
```

?>

```
sistema.php

<?php  
if (isset($_POST['pagina'])) {
    include 'classes/pessoa.php';

    $p = new Pessoa();

    $p->cadastrar($_POST['nome'], $_POST['idade'], $_POST['peso'], $_POST['altura']);

    echo "<div>".$p->exibir()."</div>";
}
else{
    echo "teste";
}

echo '<br><br><a href="../index.php">Voltar<a>';
```

?>

Comment: Você editou a questão mas não deu o feedback, foi erro na hora de colocar no SO ou estava errado mesmo?

Comment: eu retornei o valor e ainda nao funcionou

Comment: aparece esse erro : "Notice: Undefined property: Pessoa::$calcularImc in C:\xampp\htdocs\exemploFormulario\php\classes\Pessoa.php on line 69" E a linha 69 é onde esta: <b>imc</b>: $this->calcularImc<br>";

Comment: Coloque o erro no artigo, vai ficar mais fácil visualizar. O erro está aqui:

$this->calcularImc

Você está executando como se fosse uma propriedade, mas na verdade é um método. Mude para $this->calcularImc()

Comment: Acabei de fazer isso, porem esta aparecendo o () como resultado.

Comment: Tente assim

<b>imc</b>: ".$this->calcularImc()."<br>";

Comment: tentei e deu o erro: Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function Pessoa::calcularImc(), 0 passed in C:\xampp\htdocs\pw1\exemploFormulario\php\classes\Pessoa.php on line 69 and exactly 2 expected in C:\xampp\htdocs\pw1\turma_a\exemploFormulario\php\classes\Pessoa.php:49 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\exemploFormulario\php\classes\Pessoa.php(69): Pessoa->calcularImc() #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\exemploFormulario\php\sistema.php(9): Pessoa->exibir() #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\exemploFormulario\php\classes\Pessoa.php on line 49

Comment: muito obrigado pela ajudar mas consegui resolver com  a resposta do roberto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro está em seu método calcularImc que recebe 2 parâmetros e você não está passando. Tem duas soluções.

A primeira

Substituir no seu método exibir:

> `$this->calcularImc` para `{$this->calcularImc($this->peso, $this->altura)}`

A segunda solução que é a mais recomendada

Modificar seu método calcularImc para utilizar os atributos:

```
public function calcularImc()
{
    return $this->peso/($this->altura * $this->altura);
}
```

E modificar seu método exibir:

> `$this->calcularImc` para `{$this->calcularImc()}`

Comment: muito obrigado deu certo

Comment: Por nada. Que bom. Bons estudos com Orientação a Objetos.